CLLocationManager not starting SWIFT
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("appeared")
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        print(" done setting up")
    }

    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var distanceSpan = 1000
    let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 31.889484, longitude: -11.035278)
    var currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 38.889484, longitude: -77.035278)
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("location map updated")
        let longitude = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude
        let latitude = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude
        self.currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
    }
}

The "didUpdateLocation" is never being called. Why?
I also am never receiving a request for the location (
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization )
